# How to configure Apache as a reverse proxy by extracting the host from the path

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I'd like to configure Apache as a reverse proxy for that determines the URL to proxy to dynamically by parsing the path of the requested URL.

For example, the URL `http://proxy-server/app/your-app` would get proxied to `http://your-app:8000/` and `http://proxy-server/app/your-app/some/path` would go to `http://your-app:8000/some/path`.

The problem I'm running into with the below configuration is that `http://proxy-server/app/your-app/` works just fine, but `http://proxy-server/app/your-app/some/path` gets redirected to `http://proxy-server/some/path`, which gives a 404 error.

I've tried using just `mod_proxy` like this

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/app/([^/]+)(?:/(.*))?$" "http://$1:8000/$2"
```

And I've tried it with `mod_rewrite`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/app/"
RewriteRule "^([^/]+)/?$" "http://$1:8000/" [E=CONTAINER:$1,P]
RewriteRule "^([^/]+)/(.+)$" "http://$1:8000/$2" [E=CONTAINER:$1,P]

ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
ProxyPassReverse "/app/" "http://${CONTAINER}:8000/" interpolate
```

When I `curl -D - http://proxy-server/app/your-app` I get an `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` response. When I `curl -D - http://proxy-server/app/your-app/some/path` I get a `HTTP/1.1 301 Move Permanently` response with `Location: /some/path/`.

I'm not sure where the 301 is coming from. Neither Apache nor the app running on that host should be returning a 301, but the `Location` header made me think it might be that the reverse proxy isn't set up to correctly rewrite URLs from the remote to which it is proxying, which is why I added the `ProxyPassReverse` directive above. But I still can't get it working.

Any insight into how to set this up would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did have the `ProxyPassReverse` directive configured incorrectly for this scenario.

The remote server to which I was proxying (a Django app) was issuing redirects by setting the `Location` header to a path, not a full URL. So I had to configure Apache like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/app/([^/]+)(?:/.*)?$" - [E=CONTAINER:$1]

ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
ProxyPass "/app/${CONTAINER}/" "http://${CONTAINER}:8000/" interpolate
ProxyPassReverse "/app/${CONTAINER}/" "http://${CONTAINER}:8000/" interpolate

# This guarantees that any Location headers that are just absolute paths
# get rewritten
ProxyPassReverse "/app/${CONTAINER}/" "/" interpolate
```

That last line is the key. It tells Apache that if it gets a `Location: /some/path/` header, it should rewrite it as `Location: /app/your-app/some/path/`. The first `ProxyPassReverse` directive would have triggered only if Apache had received `Location: http://${CONTAINER}:8000/some/path/`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `mod_dir` module redirects requests for a directory path that don't have a trailing slash to one that does. This is controlled by the [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive. Disabling `DirectorySlash` will turn off this behavior:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

It may be helpful to specify `-v` with `curl` to print verbose output.

Comment: Good catch. That probably is where the redirect is coming from. This doesn't really fix the issue, though, it just avoids the problem in this one case. The remotes that are being proxied to should be able to issue redirects and the reverse proxy should be able to handle it, which is what the `ProxyPassReverse` setting is supposed to handle (or at least that's my understanding). So I think there's still something wrong with my configuration.